# Angular 2 dependency injection in pipes

Tags: typescript, angular

How can i inject dependencies like a service into angular2 pipes?

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyService} from './service';

//How i am injecting MyService to the pipe?

@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value:number, args:string[]) : any {
    return Math.pow(value, parseInt(args[0] || '1', 10));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can inject the dependency in the constructor like this:

```
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public testService: TestService) {

  }

  transform(value:number, args:string[]) : any {
    // you can access this.testService here
    return Math.pow(value, parseInt(args[0] || '1', 10));
  }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure you add this dependency to the app module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    providers: [..., TestService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to inject `TestService` for only the Pipe instead of the whole application? e.g. With a `providers` array.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The pipe decorator only except name and pure properties.

Comment: @maximedupre you could use an `NgModule` that only declares your pipe. The `TestService` would be provided in that module only, thus the `TestService` is only available to the pipe and not the whole application.

Comment: I am having an issue with this because I have a service that consumes the pipe as well (the service injected into the pipe is the route to decorate with the url). So In this case Typescript throws an error if I don't inject the ActivatedRoute into my service and pass it through `private prefPipe: PagePreferencesPipe = new PagePreferencesPipe(routerFromService);` Is there a way I can avoid this by injecting into the service or something?